# QGIS 3: How to filter OpenStreetMap nodes by their role in a relation

Tags: openstreetmap, qgis-3, quickosm

I want to export a relation from OSM, style it and export it again to SVG or some other format to use it in other applications.

For fetching the data I use QuickOSM and the following query:

```xml
<osm-script output="xml" output-config="" timeout="25">
  <union into="_">
    <id-query type="relation" ref="9022117"/>
    <recurse from="relations" type="relation-node"/>
    <recurse from="relations" type="relation-way"/>
  </union>
  <union into="_">
    <item from="_" into="_"/>
    <recurse from="_" into="_" type="down"/>
  </union>
  <print e="" from="_" geometry="skeleton" ids="yes" limit="" mode="body" n="" order="id" s="" w=""/>
</osm-script>
```

In my example I am using relation 9022117, a train connection. I want to map the connection as a red line with the stops. I got the data, the red line and I got the nodes styled as I want. However right now all of the nodes are styled that way.

[image]

When looking at the relation I can see the member nodes like this:

```xml
...
    <member type="node" ref="6076636356" role="stop"/>
    <member type="node" ref="6076650267" role="stop"/>
    <member type="node" ref="6077173089" role="stop"/>
    <member type="node" ref="6076666707" role="stop"/>
...
```

How can I filter the nodes in QGIS, so that I can only style/display the nodes which are set as members with role stop in the relation? QuickOSM seems to not include the members.

Answer (score 1):

So what I ended up doing now was to just manually extract the IDs from the relation in the .osm file using Visual Studio Code.

I then used the ids in a query in QGIS. Specifically I used a filter query with **in** and passed the list of ids.

[image]

However as this solution requires quite some manual work and an automated solution would be nice, I still leave the question open for now.